# Ask for <strike>root</strike> password to get desired privileges

Tags: c++, c, linux, permissions, linux-kernel

I'm loading a Linux Kernel Module from my application via libkmod ( https://github.com/profusion/kmod ) and everything works fine (as in the module gets loaded and unloaded when I want), but for that to happen I need to run my entire program as root (or a privileged user, say in sudoers).
I'd like to be able to load the application as normal user, then, ask for <strike>root</strike> user's password (user is in sudoers), `setuid(0);` just to load the module and then restore the old uid.

My question is: How can I ask for <strike>root</strike>user's password via some kind of UI dialog (as the one that appears whenever I try to change something via KDE's control panel)?

Regards

EDIT: I won't accept methods like `system("kdesu/gksu my_app")` or `popen()` and family. I'm looking for a programatical way for invoking a password prompt. I also won't accept DE-specific answers (see kdesu and gksu). I'm looking for something that will work on every XDG-compliant DE. Finally, there is no need for the password prompt to exist. I can create a simple dialog in Qt and ask for the password, then use it to call whatever function that accepts it, say something like `setuid('password', 0)`.

Comment: -1 Your "won't accept" criterea reveal rejection of understanding of sound design practices and how security on unix-style operating systems works, in particular the association between a process and a security context.

Comment: My "won't accept" criteria reveals rejection to poorly, hackish and bad methods of doing what I'm asking for. Nothing more and nothing less. I'd accept whatever answer fits my needs or an answer that explains why what I'm asking is impossible.

Comment: You might do well to consider what can actually be done with the password.  The kernel cares not a bit about passwords.  Rather, all a password does is (if it checks) convince an existing setuid executable such as *login* or *sudo* to launch a shell or other requested process as a given potentially different user, such as the superuser.  So ultimately, you are going to have to execute some  setuid program to do what you want.  Obtaining the user's password yourself won't change that, and it's bad practice besides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just knowing a user's password will not be useful for calling `setuid` because you need the `CAP_SETUID` privilege to change the uid (which usually means you need to be root).

Please note that if you have the `CAP_SETUID` privilege, you do not need the user's password; any password checking must be done by the program that calls `setuid`.

---

The 'proper' way to allow your program to load a kernel module is to write a simple helper program that does *nothing* but loading the module, and install that helper as set-user-ID-root.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking too about something else that'd load the kernel and nothing more, but this makes me wonder another two things. a) How can I call that other binary? via system() (or family)? b) How will that other binary get privileges in order to load the kernel? Via chown root; chmod ugo+xs?

Comment: a) Use whatever works (system, fork+exec, posix_spawn, etc.). b) That's what I meant with set-user-ID-root.

Comment: Ok, that is going to be the fallback (at least for now). Thank you for the answer. I'll accept it and give you +50 if I don't get any other alternative. I'd really like to be able to gain privileges inside my code, without having to chown/chmod any binary.

Comment: The OS is deliberately designed so that gaining privileges requires `CAP_SETUID`; anything else would subvert the entire security mechanism.

Comment: @alexandernst - this is where your lack of understanding of unix shows.  The entire point is that you can only gain privileges if they  were already granted to the program.   Usually, that is done by executing an setuid executable (where the pre-existing grant is tied to the executable file), or executing a setuid executable which will in turn execute your program.  Anything which lets an existing, not previously privileged process switch to executing as root is categorized as a "bug" and patched with high priority.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thank you for clarifying that. Now I know.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `pam` to authenticate. Example http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/pam/pam-sample-appl.html

Comment: There isn't such a package in Arch that will provide "openpam.h". How do you compile that? But anyways, going further more, I can't see how this helps me in any way. This is just running exec() (which is pretty much the same as system(), with some small variations). I *don't* want to run a shell command, I want to gain proper privileges *inside* my code.

Comment: Also, just to be sure... Does this require chown-ing the binary to root and setting +s? If so, this really isn't what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You DO NOT want to ask for the root password. I have worked on systems where I have no root-access, but I do have `sudo` rights. This is not uncommon - especially if the `sudoers` is set up to only allow a small set of commands.

This is what `sudo` (and it's friends with graphical user interfaces) is for. If the user can't get himself into the `sudoers` file, then he has no right to know the password for root. If the system hasn't got `sudo` on it, then it probably ought to have it - it is a much safer solution than using `root` as a user for everything. On my home machine, I use `sudo` on a daily basis, but rarely do I log in as `root`. I think that is exactly as it should be.

Comment: I'm sorry, I explained myself wrong. Actually I don't want to ask for root's password but for user's password (assuming he is already in sudoers)

Comment: So, use `sudo` or one of the graphical variants. There is no good reason for doing something else.

Comment: I don't wish my entire application to run in sudo mode. I just want to gain sudoers privileges for a second, enough time to do what I want, then get back to limited user privileges.

Comment: Bearing in mind that if the app is doing `setuid` (or one of it's friends) it needs to be installed by someone with `root` privileges, I'm not entirely sure what problem we're trying to solve here. Either the app itself needs to be run under root privileges, or it can be installed in such a way that it can be run only by certain users. Is that not good enough? It works for many other types of apps.

Comment: Well, my app is loading a kernel module via kmod. I'd like the app to gain privileges just for the amount of time needed to load the module, then drop privileges and run in normal user mode. (And please, don't suggest changing the entire app workflow, that's the design I have, I'm just looking for a way to get user's password and gain privileges for a second, then drop them).

Comment: So, look at the sources of `sudo` etc? But you still need `setuid` or similar. I still think this doesn't seem like the "right" thing to do.

Comment: Well, "System config" (in KDE) runs in user mode, but when you try to change some system settings (like date/time) it asks you for a password, applies the changes and then drops privileges. I'd like to do pretty much the same.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. And the way to check how to do that is by looking at how either those tools do that [as was suggested in a comment above], or how `sudo` works (which also does similar things). I would be very surprised if the system config tools aren't actually just invokin `sudo`, but I've never looked at the source code, so I can't say.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm not sure about KDE, but Gnome's version is `/usr/bin/gksudo`.  This has the added advantage of your gnome keyring, which can (based on how you configure it) keep that password cached for 30 minutes or some such so you don't have to repeatedly type it.  Note that you must be in the `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: OK, let's say I'm already in sudoers, how can I call gksudo? I'd like to avoid ```system("gksudo .....");``` as that's really ugly.

Comment: @alexandernst, Use a pipe?

Comment: @AnishRam I'm not sure what do you mean. How is a pipe helping here?

Comment: You need to run the `gksudo` command. So, use the [`popen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/popen.html) command, specify, `gksudo` as the command, use `fgets` or some such to read the output and parse it.

Comment: No, you're getting me wrong. I don't want to use system() calls as that's just ugly, popen() is exactly the same. I'm looking for something more programatical than just launching a command as if my app is a script.

Comment: you do not want do depend on gksudo if your application is not Gnome one. KDE has `/usr/lib/kde4/libexec/kdesu` and `/usr/bin/kdesudo`. However the safest way would be to look at the source code of those KCM modules or PartitionManager, which requests the root privileges in similar way

Comment: @alexandernst - you really, really, do need to launch a separate command, since it is only that fixed command's process, and not your entire program, which should run in a privileged context.